# How to validate a user control loaded in the page programatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, user-controls

I want to ask  how to validate client side and server side in the following case :

I have a web page which i load a user control in programatically like this :

---

## in the page_load :

```
  if (Request.QueryString["PageNew"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["PageNew"]))
            {
                page_new_name = Request.QueryString["PageNew"];
                ctrl = (MyBaseControl)LoadControl("UserControls/" + page_new_name);
            }

 if (ctrl != null)
            {
                pnl_PageNew_UC.Controls.Add(ctrl);
            }
```

---

This page contains a `button(Confirm)` . i want this button to validate some controls in my user control before confirming ,How to do this ,Some explanation please?

Comment: Just a side-note: `Request.QueryString` is as `string` so you could shorten the first line to: `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["PageNew"]))`

Comment: Can't you simply add your validation controls to the usercontrol?

Comment: The Validators in the UserControl(s) should be triggered already on submit. You can force validation via `Page.Validate("UC_ValidationGroup"); if(Page.IsValid){// ...}`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter:Thanks a lot, Could u explain more please, the `button[Confirm]` is in my page not in my user control and that button have to validate the server controls in my loaded user control.

Comment: @just_name: As i've tried to explain, you could use `ValidationGroups` in your `UserControl` and trigger them via `Page.Validate("UC_ValidationGroup");`, where `UC_ValidationGroup` is the name of the group.

Comment: Read about [Page.Validate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh.aspx)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter::thanks a lot,, It works ,i hoped to be an answer not a comment to tick as an answer.. Thanks a lot